# Just what is a high transaction database

Tags: database, transactions, definition, transactional

silly question I know, but what is the definition of high transaction database? how many transactions per second constitutes a high, medium and low transactional database?

Comment: It might be more advantageous to determine if your use case generates high, medium, or low rates of transactions more so than any particular database.  The mixture of reads and writes, duration of bursts, etc. all really matter in determining the appropriate storage backend.  Some database engines cope much better than others with high writes and infrequent reads for instance.

Answer (score 3):

Heres some thought: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_nielsen/archive/2007/12/12/10-lessons-from-35k-tps.aspx .

Generally, any banking and financial trading system can be classed as a high-transaction system. But modern social networking websites like Twitter, Facebook etc are also joining the group. I probably didn't answer your question fully, but it should certainly give you some perspective.

[EDIT:] seems like anything >=30k transactions per second are high-transaction systems, so analogously, anything less than that should fall in low and medium transactions.

Comment: The link in this comment requires (at least) an account to be read. Would it be possible to provide a link that doesn't require such link?